# Why does filter() return an empty array?

Tags: javascript

Why does the code below log [] instead of [200, 3.14, 7, 13]?

```
let randomNumbers = [375, 200, 3.14, 7, 13, 852];
let smallNumbers = randomNumbers.filter(function(number) {
return number.length < 250;});

console.log(smallNumbers); // prints [] — empty array
```

Thank you!

Comment: Numbers don’t have a length. `(375).length === undefined`

Comment: @Ryan iirc you can assign it a length property? Might be silently ignored though (testing)

Comment: @SterlingArcher: You could put a `length` on `Number.prototype`, I guess? But the point is there isn’t one already.

Comment: @SterlingArcher, the condition does not rely on the length, it is a wrong use of `length`, but does not lead to answer the question.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate of the marked question; it's asking *how* to get the length of a number, this one is asking *why* the filtered array is empty. It just so happens that the problem was incorrectly using `.length` on a number.

Comment: @NinaScholz I can agree to that, however my second vote would go towards closing as a typo/syntax issue or "why doesn't my code work"

Answer (score 2):

A number does not have a `length` property, just check the variable without.

`undefined` in a condition with smaller or greater condition returns `false`. The result array is empty, because of the condition's `false` for every item.

```js
var randomNumbers = [375, 200, 3.14, 7, 13, 852],
    smallNumbers = randomNumbers.filter(function(number) {
        return number < 250;
    });

console.log(smallNumbers);
```

Comment: To explain *why* the array was empty, non-existing properties return `undefined`, so `number.length` resulted in comparing `undefined < 250`, which evaluates to `false`.